# how to install Ghost CMS in firebase hosting subdirectory

Tags: firebase, ghost-blog

This question has been asked (several years ago),

(https://forum.ghost.org/t/installing-ghost-on-a-firebase-hosted-site-as-a-subdirectory/6033/3)

but was wondering if such an implementation is possible, and wondering if anyone can offer some advice on this. I'm looking to integrate/install Ghost CMS onto my subdirectory `example.com/blog` and wondering if it's possible in the first place.

My website is hosted on firebase hosting, and written with a JS/nodeJS stack.
Feels like many complexities, so also looking if that's a cleaner way and resources will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about a subdirectory, but if a subdomain is possible (i.e. blog.example.com)  that would be a super easy solution.

Comment: Yep, I think there are resources on those, basically, it's more like a standalone site. was wondering if the subdirectory option is possible...

Comment: Do you have any resources for hosting ghost CMS on a subdomain?

Comment: No resources, just personal experience.  I was able to deploy it with minor modifications as a Cloud Function and then I set up Firebase Hosting to rewrite all traffic to that function.  However you'll need to create a custom ORM adapter to work with Firestore/RTDB and I never got around to it so that's where I stopped.

Comment: Tough haha, did you decide to work with another cms then?